# Any way to get interval based audio blob using RecordRTC

Tags: webrtc, recordrtc

I am implementing something which takes video/audio using client brwoser and at specific interval upload the chunks of that to server.

Now on server side I need to do something with audio and then broadcast the same video with the updated audio to other clients.

I am using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/RecordRTC/README.md) to capture audio and video. For video I have method **ondataavailable** which gives me time based blobs. Can I have similar for audio as well? Any better suggestion to implement this flow also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Either capture audio-only stream using getUserMedia, or generate a new media-stream object where you need to add only audio tracks.

```
var recorder;
var listOfBlobs = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true // video tracks are enabled only for demo purpose
}).then(function(camera) {
    hiddenVideo.srcObject = camera; // make sure that camera tracks are not released/stoppped/inactive

    var audioOnlyStream = new MediaStream();
    camera.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(audioTrack) {
        audioOnlyStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
    });

    recorder = RecordRTC(audioOnlyStream, {
        type: 'audio',
        mimeType: 'audio/webm',
        recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder,
        timeSlice: 1000,
        ondataavailable: function(blob) {
            listOfBlobs.push(blob);
        }
    });
});

btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
    recorder.stopRecording(function() {
        var singleBlob = new Blob(listOfBlobs, {
            type: 'audio/webm'
        });

        var url = URL.createObjectURL(singleBlob);
        window.open(url);
    });
};
```

Comment: I want to capture audio/wav audio as this is required to process on server side. I saw it's possible using **StereoAudioRecorder** but not using **MediaStreamRecorder**. But when I use **StereoAudioRecorder** I don't get time based blobs. Is there any way to get that? Also I need desiredSampleRate of 16000.